# How would i go about doing the class library and inserting it into my main form, preferably with an example?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, class-library

Wpf and class libraries

[image: Wpf and class libraries]

So basically I have created a WPF form as required, but I'm not sure how to do the class library and what to exactly do in the library and insert it into the WPF and use it. If anyone could help I'd really appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: Add a new project to your solution and choose Class Library. Put all the business logic there and reference the library from the WPF application.

Comment: So basically I would do my calculations in the class library?

Comment: Yes. The aim is to separate UI and logic, so you in priciple could build a different UI (app or Web) using the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

Basically with a class library you can decide what code to expose.

Inside the class library you can create everything you want. (Like: Classes/Views and so on)

Inside your WPF (UI Project) you can reference the Class Library to use the exposed Methods.

Doing so cleans your project and seperates it.

For example:

You have a Class Library named Calculator.CORE.
Inside of Calculator.CORE you have the Methods Add, Substract, Divide and Multiply.

Now you can reference CALCULATOR.CORE in your UI Project and use it.
This way you can maintain the Library (make changes when needed) and you dont have to update the UI Project in most cases.

**EDIT: Maybe show us what you are working with exactly then we can help you more specifically.**